# Find the polynomial whose zeros are reciprocal of each other

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, roots

I have been trying this sum taking the zeros as $\alpha$ and $\alpha^{-1}$, using the formula $x^2-(\alpha+\beta)x+\alpha \beta$.
However I am stuck in this step:
$$
\alpha x^2-(\alpha^2+1)x+\alpha=0.
$$
This could have been the answer, but $\alpha$ is not defined in the question and hence cannot be a part of the answer. I have searched the internet for this question but nowhere the answer seems to be available.

The source of the question is unknown, I found this question in a really old school question paper and that school is not in existence anymore.

Comment: $x^2-sx+1$ (with $|s|\ge2$ if you want  a real polynomial with real roots).

Comment: "*This could have been the answer, but...*" $\;-\;$ That _is_ the answer, with $\alpha$ being an arbitrary constant. You should not expect a unique answer, since you are not given the actual roots, but just the relation between them of being reciprocal. Given that there are two roots, that constraint leaves one degree of freedom, which is consistent with the solution depending on one arbitrary constant.

Comment: I don't understand the close votes, honestly. This is a well articulated question, with enough context to frame it and answer it.

Comment: @AnneBauval gives nice and quick comment/answer. Next, we can conclude how $a=c$ is mandatory in such polynomials $\left(P(x)=ax^2+bx+c\right)$! Proof: $\alpha \cdot \alpha^{-1}= \tfrac{c}{a}=1 \iff c=a$.

Comment: Well I was thinking the same honestly. I have always been driven by the thought that a self defined variable cannot be a part of the answer, well that changes now. Thank you so much everyone for the help :D

Comment: Don't worry $\alpha$ can be any number other than zero. I mean $\alpha \in \mathbb{R} - \{ 0 \}$

Comment: Trying only with rationals $\dfrac mn$ you have always the equation $mnx^2-(m^2+n^2)x+mn=0$ and if you want try with integers, you make $n=1$ in which case the solutions of $mx^2-(m^2+1)x+m=0$ are $m$ and $\dfrac 1m$. It would have some interest, maybe, try this with algebraic numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your $\alpha x^2-(\alpha^2+1)x+\alpha,$ or dividing by $\alpha$ if you want a monic polynomial:
$$x^2-\left(\alpha+\frac1\alpha\right)x+1$$
*is* the answer, with $\alpha\ne0$ being an arbitrary constant. Indeed, for an arbitrary quadratic polynomial $x^2-sx+p,$ the product of the two roots is $p$ (their sum being $s$).

If you want $\alpha\in\Bbb R,$ this (family of) polynomial(s) coincides with
$$x^2-sx+1,$$
with $|s|\ge2.$